# What does the <vm:SimpleViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/> mean in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM, actually started just a week back and I am trying to code up an application using both WPF and MVVM, while coding up an example I came across the following statement `<vm:SimpleViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>` and I am trying to reason about it. I understand what 'x:' refers to, its the default XAML namespace mentioned in the XAML file and I have created a namespace for my own ViewModel class that the UI will be interacting with and I have given it an alias "vm" and SimpleViewModel is the ViewModel for my application, the statement for the purposes of reference is `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MVVM_Tutorial"`.

My Reasoning for the statement `<vm:SimpleViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>` is that a Window is a XAML element and has a resource dictionary that it refers to resolve and refer to certain elements, hence inside its resource dictionary which is defined in the "x:" namespace we are assigning a variable called "Key" whose value is the SimpleViewModel class defined in the "vm:" namespace. Just want to know if I am right with my reasoning or is there something that I am missing and would want to know proceeding further from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XAML is just markup that describes an object graph.  Code is also markup that describes an object graph.  I can say this

```
var window = new Window();
window.DataContext = new MyNamespace.MyViewModel();
```

or I can write the exact same thing like this

```
<Window xmlns:blahblah="clr-namespace:Normal.Xmlns.Deleted.For.Brevity"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:MyViewModel />
    <!-- snip -->
```

**Any object that can be instantiated in code can be used in xaml**.  There are some restrictions (e.g., default public constructor without arguments), but for the most part this is true.  XAML just defines an object graph that is deserialized at runtime.

Since any type can be referred to in xaml, you could, hypothetically, have moved that instance of `MyViewModel` to a resource dictionary and referred to it via a StaticResource or a DynamicResource.  Note, anything you put in a resource dictionary has to have a key, assigned via x:Key:

```
<Window xmlns:blahblah="clr-namespace:Normal.Xmlns.Deleted.For.Brevity"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource lolderp}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <this:MyViewModel x:Key="lolderp" />
    <!-- snip -->
```

XAML is a subset of XML, and uses XML namespaces to map to code namespaces in the current, or other, assemblies.  It's how the framework knows what object MyViewModel refers to.  To learn more, [read this link on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, Will your answer is really helpful to visualize what might it do in resolving everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone else can chime in with more clarification...

In the xaml file, the references of

"xmlns:[something]="clr-namespace:[yourProjectOrLibrary]".

Since your code-behind can be verbose with long name space references, and your SOLUTION may be made up of multiple projects (such as different DLLs), when the XAML is processed, it uses the "xmlns" as a reference to whatever "yourProjectOrLibrary" is...  In your case the project/class "MVVM_Tutorial".

Now, the "vm".  This is just an "alias" within the xaml, so anytime it is referencing a

The xaml knows where it originates to get resolution to control, properties, types, etc.

As for the "x:Key" part...  Not positive, but when I was first building out my customized themes, also ran into confusion about the x:Key.  My interpretation of this was found to be x:Key is like a private reference, but by being given the name ..x:Key="viewModel"... is making this "name" available later within the xaml file.

This "key" can then be referenced later in the xaml...  For example,

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CTButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <!-- Start border of button to have a rounded corners -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then later within the theme, I could reference this "Key"... in my case "CTButton".  So if I wanted multiple controls to use / derive from same control template, I could have them reference it...

```
<someControl>
   <Style>
      <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CTButton}" />
   </Style>
</someControl
```

Again, I don't get EVERYTHING about all the xaml markup, but hopefully clarifies this for you some.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer but I am like trying to understand it from the conceptual point of it as to how the XAML actually refers a namespace and because it has a resource dictionary how does it resolve everything up. I think of XAML markup as a set of dictionary objects which it uses to resolve all the elements it containes.

Comment: @AnkitSablok, the "alias" (vm in your case) is how it finds things in the associated project ("mvvm_tutorial").  Depending on adding different controls from different libraries could change the "alias" reference from one xaml to another where VStudio automatically will assign aliases such as "src", "src1", "src2" in  the order they are added, but you can always rename the alias to help maintain consistency in your project...